# Переадресация с любого ip адреса

Tags: unix, dns, tcp-ip

Пользователь запрашивает данные по ip-адресу(например через протокол http,ftp,ssh). Как реализовать возможность переадресации всех адресов, на один адрес? То есть запросили 213.2.32.43 а выдает 5.2.4.2 для любого запрошенного ip адреса.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/124184/iptables-change-destination-ip-without-dnat

Comment: Там идет переадрасация, которую можно и в hosts прописать. Немного не поняли вопрос. Надо чтобы по запросу к любому адресу, возвращались данные только с одного указанного адреса

Comment: Так в вопросе по ссылке именно это и происходит, единственное различие - там  требуется подменять целевой IP для одного конкретного адреса, а Вам надо для всех.